# C# Forms, DataTable , DataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, datatable

I have this simple code here. 
 
The *data Grid View 1* shows all the contents of *dt* (DataTable) in the form. 
When you click *button1* after you have **changed the sort order** of any column, 
you get a *'NullReferenceException'* error.
When i click *button1* **without changing the sort order** , i get no errors.
How do you explain that ?

Any help appreciated.
I have spent almost 6 hours trying to solve this.

```
Form1.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dt.Columns.Add("0", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(00, 01);
            dt.Rows.Add(10, 11);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Clear();
            dt.Columns.Add("0", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
            dt.Rows.Add(00, 01);
            dt.Rows.Add(10, 11);
        }
    }
}

Form1.Designer.cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {       
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
            this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 172);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(260, 207);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    }
}
Program.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I dont have any experience to use debugger, if you go and open this project you will see the problem . the code is 20 lines. i made this to demonstrate the problem. if you DONT change sort order on any column , it doesnt give you error , if you change sort order it gives null exception.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn

Comment: The problem is that something is null that shouldn't be. You need to set a breakpoint in your button click method and inspect it to see what line this is happening on and what value is null that shouldn't be.

Comment: No, it's the most common error and it's almost always the same reason. There is nothing random about it. Using the debugger is *much, much* faster than posting a question on SO.

Comment: null reference is also one of the easiest to figure out- it's null, and it shouldn't be- figure out why.

Comment: If you don't want help, don't ask. You have a bug in a 20-line program. Clearly there is something to debug.

Comment: put a break point on your button click, and then click it- then F11 to step into. Use the immediate window and look at each variable eg : ?dt[0][0] or ?dt etc. Debugging is the spice of life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatable is bound to the grid and is getting messed up- maybe someone can give a more detailed answer as to why, but this is the answer to fix your problem.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dt.Columns.Add("0", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add(00, 01);
        dt.Rows.Add(10, 11);
    }
```

Comment: this code works , thank you very much , i ll try to figure out why now :)

Comment: also tested TechneWare's and his works as well. It is something with the grid being bound to the source.

Comment: it does work, but i also want to clear the whole datagridview, in my app im using 1 datagridview and show different database tables in it, with different column in each table so that code wasnt enough

Comment: um.. shouldnt dt = new DataTable(); give me an error  since i have already defined dt ? does dt = new DataTable();  basically means "delete old dt and create a new empty DataTable dt " ?

Comment: No it won't give you an error- and yes, you are creating a new table in memory and then redefining everything.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that you are pulling the data table out from under dataGridView1, so its trying to access objects that no longer exist.

try your button event this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Clear();
    //dt.Columns.Clear();
    //dt.Columns.Add("0", typeof(int));
    //dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
    dt.Rows.Add(00, 01);
    dt.Rows.Add(10, 11);

}
```

Comment: how do you explain that it works when i dont change order of columns(ascending/descending) , and it doesnt when i change the order of a column ?

Comment: Without the source for the data grid view object I don't.  It complained that something was not found, I discovered via the DEBUGGER that clearing the columns from your table and re-adding them was what made it unhappy.  And thats all the time I have for this one..

Comment: thank you,  its weird because clearing the columns from your table and re-adding them, works if you don't change the order of columns. i mean ... i dont see the problem since i basically delete everything from the table , and then i create it from scratch

Comment: I guess I do have time..The data table object still exists, but its columns, that you just asked the grid view to sort on no longer exist.  It might be different if you disposed of the dataTable all together and rebound the data grid view.

Comment: hmm i ll look into it . but for right now , i dont understand why it doesnt work. im telling the program to  "clear"  then "clear columns" so we are left with an empty datatable and then we add some rows (00,01) and (10,11) ,  Note: if you remove the  last line 'dt.Rows.Add(10, 11);' and you change any columns order and then you click the button , it works.

Comment: Clear only clears the rows not the schema of the table (ie columns, name, bindings, if you keyed it, etc) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: dont you see my code ? dt.Clear(); dt.Columns.Clear(); right in the button1_Click function